# show data with decode function in oracle

Tags: oracle, concatenation, decode

original data (image)
[image]
I want to display my data by concatenating several columns. But the data that appears less than perfect: there is a comma behind at the end of the concatenations, like the picture shows:

[image: http://i1207.photobucket.com/albums/bb476/daniwarrior/decode1.jpg]

Here is the query that I created in oracle 10g

```
    select id_pegawai, 
    whitelist_pembayaran||decode(whitelist_pembayaran,null,null,', ')||
    whitelist_pemasang||decode(whitelist_pemasang,null,null,', ')||
    whitelist_jenis_iklan||decode(whitelist_jenis_iklan,null,null) as whitelist,

    blacklist_pembayaran||decode(blacklist_pembayaran,null,null,', ')||
    blacklist_pemasang||decode(blacklist_pemasang,null,null,', ')||
    blacklist_jenis_iklan||decode(blacklist_jenis_iklan,null,null) as blacklist
    from verifikator order by id_verifikator desc
```

Comment: the question is poor without linking it in our minds with previous question. You should show an input, a desired output and what you tried. You gave us only the last two :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you just want to remove the comma at the end? `RTRIM` it.

```
select id_pegawai,
       rtrim(whitelist_pembayaran || decode(whitelist_pembayaran, null, null, ', ') ||
              whitelist_pemasang || decode(whitelist_pemasang, null, null, ', ') ||
              whitelist_jenis_iklan, ',') as whitelist,

       rtrim(blacklist_pembayaran || decode(blacklist_pembayaran, null, null, ', ') ||
              blacklist_pemasang || decode(blacklist_pemasang, null, null, ', ') ||
              blacklist_jenis_iklan, ',') as blacklist
  from verifikator
 order by id_verifikator desc
```